# Crystal Report Rpt File is showing garbage chars in place of arabic

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, unicode, crystal-reports

I got a rpt file (crystal report file) from my team-mate. When I open in my VS I am seeing garbage in place of arabic. E.g, :ÅÓã ÇáãäÔÃÉ

When I translate that garbage from English to Arabic, I am getting correct Arabic value, like

https://translate.google.com/#en/ar/%3A%C3%85%C3%93%C3%A3%20%C3%87%C3%A1%C3%A3%C3%A4%C3%94%C3%83%C3%89

In here :ÅÓã ÇáãäÔÃÉ is transalated correctly to إسم المنشية

Answer (score 0):

Set the font for that particular field to a font that supports Unicode Encoding

**Arial Unicode MS** 
should do the trick

Comment: Does the field contain both english as well as arabic value for different records?